# Store the reference to a method without losing classes changes C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, storing-data

Basically I have achieved storing the methods but when I call them its like they are calling in a new Instance of an object instead of the object itself.

When I call the method it just prints 0

This is where I use it. It doesn't matter how many times I execute SumanNumero. When I call RPC_MetodoEjemplo I just get 0 (The variable is initialized with 5)

```
public class Something: NetworkBehaviour
    int x = 5;
    // Esto es un ejemplo de un rpc sin parámetros
    [ClientRPC]
    public void RPC_MetodoEjemplo()
    {
        Debug.Log(x);
    }
    
    public void SumanNumero()
    {
        x += 10;
    }
}
```

This is my approach:

```
private List<RPCMethodInfo> clientRPCMethods = new List<RPCMethodInfo>();

public RPCManager()
{
    // We obtain all the classes that inherits from NetworkBehaviour
    Type[] networkBehaviours = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .Where(x => typeof(NetworkBehaviour).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
        .ToArray();
    
    // We obtain all the methods that have the ClientRPC attribute
    foreach (Type networkBehaviour in networkBehaviours)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = networkBehaviour.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ClientRPCAttribute), false).Length > 0)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
        {
            clientRPCMethods.Add(new RPCMethodInfo(method, networkBehaviour));
        }
    }
}

// Llama a este método desde el cliente para ejecutar un RPC
public void CallRPC(string methodName, object[] parameters)
{
    foreach (var method in clientRPCMethods)
    {
        if (method.Method.Name == methodName)
        {
            method.Method.Invoke(method.Target, parameters);
            return;
        }
    }
}


public class RPCMethodInfo
{
    public MethodInfo Method { get; }
    public object Target { get; }

    public RPCMethodInfo(MethodInfo method, object target)
    {
        Method = method;
        Target = target;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an *instance* of that type in order to call any of its instance-members (like your `SumanNumero`-function). But you don't create any.

Comment: The thing is it can be so many different class that implements that methods. I just want to put [ClientRPC] in any function and call it from my RPCManager

Comment: you are passing in a **TYPE** as `Target` ... it should rather be the actual target **INSTANCE** of that type ... network is not that simple ;) You need to deal with network identities and on each client uniquely identify exactly which instance your RPC call is meant for

Comment: Yes but it could be any class in my proyect i just use
`
[ClientRPC]
any function I want in any class(){
}
`

Comment: yes ... you can do that but that is simply not how it works ^^ In (deprecated) UNet, Mirror, Photon, Netcode .. you name it .. there is a **loooot** more happening under the hood than just storing the references to those methods ... Believe me I have written my own local networking with UDP/TCP sockets ... it is not as trivial as you imagine it currently

Comment: I want to do the same thing as you. Where can find something to search on?. It is my TFG (in spain is my final proyect for the carrer) so I have 5 months to do it its not a big deal. I already have quite a lot of things but I've just discovered this error, thats the problem.

Comment: it's unclear right now how much you already have ... but as said the issue here is: You don't have any instance reference on which you want to invoke this method, you are rather passing in a `Type` which is not what `MethodInfo.Invoke` expects as the target object. you will need to implement a way for how to uniquely identify instances of your type across all network devices! Do you really need your own networking or can't you simply use one of the existing ones?

Comment: If it is also "only" for your finals ... you don't have to implement a solid networking solution - even though it is slightly more tedious simply assign unique IDs (numbers) to your objects by hand and when sending an RPC append that ID as well => the receiver uses the ID to find the according object and invokes according method on it

Comment: It is necessary to create my own because my final proyect for school is making my own. I really doesnt need to do some game with it I just have to make it, make the doc and thats it. Sorry for my english btw

Comment: Your English is just fine ;) So here is what I did: For each networked object have a unique ID - if those are all in the scene from the beginning better. If not - also have unique ID or any prefabs (can be as simple as index in an array). Then when spawning new objects first of all have a call to the Host -> reserve and return required amount of unique IDs => on spawn assign those same IDs on all clients (for the spawns you send those IDs along with the prefab index of what to spawn) => Now you only need to store all objects in dictionaries and can simply identify them by ID.

Comment: For me reflection was too slow so I rather registered specific networked services with callbacks in dictionaries directly - and used a protocol where I prepended everything to the RPC call payload like e.g.  `senderID (byte)` + `serviceID (byte/index)` + `methodID (byte)` + `networkObjectID (uint)` + `payload (byte[])`

Comment: Of course this was not as slick as just simply having `RPC` attributes but devs rather had to implement their own services accordingly in addition to the ones we provided (like e.g. NetworkIdendityService first of all ;) )

Comment: If you want to go for reflection and the magic attribute you can totally do so ... you just have to first solve the unique identity thing ... before you have that the rest doesn't really matter

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. At the end I did something with the objects as you say. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @derHugo I did something.

Its not so effective but It is only called 1 time at the begining of the game so it is not that bad.(Could be better, probably when I finish the proyect i will refactor it)

This is it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class RPCManager
{
    private Dictionary<GameObject, List<RPCInfo>> methods = new Dictionary<GameObject, List<RPCInfo>>();
    public RPCManager()
    {
        GameObject[] objetosEnEscena = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        
        foreach (GameObject objeto in objetosEnEscena)
        {
            NetworkBehaviour[] scripts = objeto.GetComponents<NetworkBehaviour>();
            
            foreach (NetworkBehaviour script in scripts)
            {
                MethodInfo[] metodos = script.GetType().GetMethods();
                
                List<RPCInfo> metodosConRPC = new List<RPCInfo>();
                
                foreach (MethodInfo metodo in metodos)
                {
                    if (metodo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ClientRPCAttribute), true).Length > 0)
                    {
                        metodosConRPC.Add(new RPCInfo(metodo, script));
                    }
                }

                methods.Add(objeto, metodosConRPC.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
    
    // This is to add a new RPC method to the list
    public void AddRPC(GameObject gameObject, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (methods.ContainsKey(gameObject))
        {
            methods[gameObject].Add(new RPCInfo(methodInfo, gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkBehaviour>()));
        }
        else
        {
            methods.Add(gameObject, new List<RPCInfo> {new RPCInfo(methodInfo, gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkBehaviour>())});
        }
    }
    
    // Call RPC
    public void CallRPC(string methodName, object[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<GameObject, List<RPCInfo>> pair in methods)
        {
            foreach (RPCInfo rpcInfo in pair.Value)
            {
                //Debug.Log(rpcInfo.toTExt());
                if (rpcInfo.methodInfo.Name == methodName)
                {
                    rpcInfo.methodInfo.Invoke(rpcInfo.target, parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public List<Type> FindNetworkBehaviourTypes()
    {
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        List<Type> networkBehaviourTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
            networkBehaviourTypes.AddRange(types.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(NetworkBehaviour))));
        }

        return networkBehaviourTypes;
    }
    
    public List<GameObject> FindGameObjectsWithNetworkBehaviour()
    {
        List<Type> networkBehaviourTypes = FindNetworkBehaviourTypes();
        List<GameObject> gameObjectsWithNetworkBehaviour = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
        {
            NetworkBehaviour[] networkBehaviours = go.GetComponents<NetworkBehaviour>();

            foreach (NetworkBehaviour nb in networkBehaviours)
            {
                if (networkBehaviourTypes.Contains(nb.GetType()))
                {
                    gameObjectsWithNetworkBehaviour.Add(go);
                    break; // No need to check this GameObject further
                }
            }
        }

        return gameObjectsWithNetworkBehaviour;
    }

    public class RPCInfo
    {
        public MethodInfo methodInfo;
        public object target;
        
        public RPCInfo(MethodInfo methodInfo, object target)
        {
            this.methodInfo = methodInfo;
            this.target = target;
        }
        
        // We use this method instead of ToString() because ToString() can only be called from the main thread
        // and this is executing in a background thread
        public string toTExt()
        {
            return "RPCInfo: " + methodInfo.Name + " " + target;
        }
    }
}
`
```